# What is the best way to fnd the highest float/double value from a string in PHP?

Tags: php

I wrote a function that gets the highest float from a string.

```php
    /**
     * @param $string
     * @return bool|float
     */
    public static function getHighestValueFromString($string) {
        preg_match_all('/\d+\.*\d*/', $string, $matches);
        return (empty($matches[0]) ? false : max(array_map('floatval', $matches[0])));
    }
```

It seems to work:

```php
var_dump(Class::getHighestValueFromString('8.5, 10.5-13.5 workdays')); // 13.5
var_dump(floatval('8.5, 10.5-13.5 workdays')); // 8.5
```

But I can't help but feel that I'm doing it in a wasteful manner, as I'm running this function twice for every order we get, isn't there a better way to do this?

Comment: I'm not following you. _"as I'm running this function twice"_ - Where? Why? And what does the `float(...)` call have to do with anything?

Comment: The method itself looks fine, and if it's working then I don't really see any reason to change it. If you mean you're literally running it twice on the same string, then just save the result somewhere - that feels like a sign that there could be some better application design going on. But honestly, stop worrying about micro-optimizations if you can. That's a fight you can't ever win.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the e-commerce framework we use has several ways and places to configure a delay for delivery. I'm building another way that depends on the day of week, but I have to get the highest value from a user editable strings in multiple places. That's why I'm running this multiple times. the `floatval(...)` is mostly to make clear why I'm doing what I'm doing.